# css autocomplete in javascript file(atom editor)

Tags: css, autocomplete, reactjs, atom-editor

I am using React and I really like the fact to I can write inline style directly in my javascript file. However, autocomplete css doesn't seems to work in Atom editor.It work fine with ".css" file, not in ".js" file. Is there an Atom package that would enable this feature? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The scope in which snippets are working is defined in the snippet file itself. There is currently no way to make snippets work in a “foreign” scope (see this [forum post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/override-or-extend-scope-of-a-snippet/28312) for reference.)

Your best option is probably adding the [language-css](https://github.com/atom/language-css/blob/master/snippets/language-css.cson) snippets to your Atom snippets (Atom > Snippets) and edit their scope accordingly (e.g. `source.css, source.js`). Alternatively, you could do the same creating a new package.